# Am I coding dummy variables for disease groups correctly in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

Normally I would code my dummy variables as follows:

| Original variable levels | Dummy_disease1 | Dummy_disease2 | Dummy_disease3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Disease 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Disease 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Disease 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

However, I dont want to know if the odds for disease 1 are different compared to *either disease 2 or 3*, but I want to specifically compare the odds for *disease 1 versus disease 3*, and *disease 2 versus disease 3*, .. (and other comparisons) To do this, I made the following dummy variables:

| Original variable levels | ?Dummy_disease1 | ?Dummy_disease2 | ?Dummy_disease3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Disease 1 | 1 | NA | 1 |
| Disease 2 | NA | 1 | 0 |
| Disease 3 | 0 | 0 | NA |

Is this OK? I am confused as this is not how dummy variables are normally computed or how the `glm` function in R would code the dummy variables.

NB. An example using the second dummy variables: Do disease 1 or disease 2 change the odds for presence of calcification compared to disease 3?:

```r
model <- glm(data=dataset, formula=presence_of_calcification ~ ?Dummy_disease1 + ?Dummy_desease2status_3cat_PIVI, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not OK.  `glm` will remove rows with missing variables.  Set disease 3 as your baseline group and `glm` will do comparisons for you.  Additional comparisons will require additional analysis.